# How to pre-fill a transient value on a JPA Entity

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

How to pre-fill a transient attribute (say accountId) on a JPA Entity. I am trying to set accountId using a constant fetched from the application environment (say appAccountId). Is this the right way to fetch this information, when a select is run on the Entity?

```
@Entity
public class Foo {

  @Value("${app.account.id}")
  private String appAccountId;

  private String transient accountId;

  @Postload 
  public void postLoad() {
      accountId = appAccountId;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add this value as a constructor parameter.

```
public class Foo {
    public Foo(@Value("${app.account.id}") String accountId) {
        this.accountId = accountId
    }
....
```

Comment: I use Builder pattern, so how do we do this would there be a way to initialize somehow

Comment: @Value("${app.account.id}")
 private transient String appAccountId; // We tried this on the JPA entity model but its empty

Comment: @Rpj it would be great to see the whole entity and way of entity creation.